# Changing the homefolder/domain

Tags: home-directory, username, user-profile

I downloaded a VMWare image from a website, and after changing the username, account and password, when I open up the terminal I still get that I'm executing it in:

```
osboxes@myUsername:~$
```

Would I be able to change it to be:

```
myUsername@myUsername:~$
```

Comment: What is your username `osboxes`? The first part is usually the username and the second part, after the `@` your hostname.

Answer (score 0):

Propably your prompt is wrong. Check `echo $PS1`, there should be `%n` which is your username. Also read and try to customize your prompt for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customise the names appearing on your terminal , open vim .bashrc

find the line 
`PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$`,

replace `u` with your username you wanted to, and change `h` to the one you wanted to replace .